# Snipcart or other similar solutions

Tags: snipcart

I am developing a website for a small business in Spain with Java, Bootstrap, jQuery and I need to integrate an ecommerce platform

Is Snipcart the best option or do you recommend any of the similar solutions that for some reason you will agree is better?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for Snipcart*

The advantage of Snipcart over other solutions is that it's independent of your other stack choices. You can select your backend tech based on what you're the most comfortable with.

If Java, Bootstrap and jQuery are requirements for the project, Snipcart won't get in the way of those. That's one of the big selling points, it can provide a lot of features for platforms that don't have a feature-full ecommerce framework.

I wouldn't know which Java-based ecommerce platform to recommend and compare to. There seems to be a few but none with big market shares or recognized name.

If Java isn't a strong requirement of the project, I'd look into PHP and Ruby/Rails solutions as they have more mature ecommerce solutions.